# How to solve this partial fraction decomposition equation?

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

$$\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)} =
 \frac{A}{(x-a)}
+\frac{B}{(x-b)}
+\frac{C}{(x-c)}$$

a,b and c are constants.

I have tried three times by hand but I can't get the right result.

The result is
$$\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)} =
 \frac{1}{(a-b)(a-c)(x-a)}
+\frac{1}{(b-a)(b-c)(x-b)}
+\frac{1}{(c-a)(c-b)(x-c)}$$

Is there any easy and clear solution to this?

Comment: $$ A = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{(x-a)}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{(x-b)(x-c)} $$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Starting with $$\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)} =
 \frac{A}{(x-a)}
+\frac{B}{(x-b)}
+\frac{C}{(x-c)}$$ multiply by ${(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}$ to get
$$1=A(x-b)(x-c)+B(x-a)(x-c)+C(x-a)(x-b)$$ Now, make 
$$x=a\implies 1=A(a-b)(a-c)\implies A= ???$$
$$x=b\implies 1=B(b-a)(b-c)\implies B= ???$$
$$x=c\implies 1=C(c-a)(c-b)\implies C= ???$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)} =
 \frac{A}{(x-a)}
+\frac{B}{(x-b)}
+\frac{C}{(x-c)}$$

Rearrange to give,
$$A = \frac{1}{(x-b)(x-c)} - \frac{B(x-a)}{(x-b)}
-\frac{C(x-a)}{(x-c)}
$$

Put $x = a$ to get

$$A = \frac{1}{(a-b)(a-c)}
$$

Similiarly,

$$B = \frac{1}{(b-a)(b-c)}
$$

And

$$C = \frac{1}{(c-a)(c-b)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$A(x-b)(x-c)+B(x-a)(x-c)+C(x-a)(x-b)=1$$
$$A(x^2-(b+c)x+bc)+B(x^2-(a+c)x-ac)+C(x^2-(a+b)x-ab)=1$$

Equate coefficients.

Coefficient of $x^2$ is 0
$$(A+B+C)x^2=0x^2$$
Thus $A+B+C=0$

You can form similar equations and then solve them by equating the coefficients of $x$ and $1$

Comment: You are definitely right and that's what I was doing, but it seems too complex to calculate by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to follow the hint by @JackD'Aurizio,  but let me spell it out in a little more detail.  Start with
$$\frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)} =
 \frac{A}{x-a}
+\frac{B}{x-b}
+\frac{C}{x-c}$$ 
Multiply by $(x-a)$:
$$\frac{1}{(x-b)(x-c)} = A + (x-a) \left( \frac{B}{x-b} + \frac{C}{x-c} \right)$$
Now set $x=a$, with the result
$$\frac{1}{(a-b)(a-c)} = A$$ because all the stuff with a factor of $(x-a)$ vanishes.

$B$ and $C$ are obtained similarly.  Voila!